# Problemas accediendo a los valores de un JSON

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo acceder al valor de `restingHeartRate`?.

Lo he intentado de varias maneras y no me lo permite.

He intentado obtener el valor de `activities-heart` de la siguiente manera:

```
actividad['activities-heart']
```

Después he intentado recorrer este valor para poder acceder y añadirlo a una lista lo que me "interesa" en una matriz para después poder recorrerla nuevamente. Sin embargo, no lo consigo.

Lo he intentado de la siguiente manera:

```
   this.servicioService.getData()
      .subscribe(actividad => {
        //console.log(actividad['activities-heart']);
        actividad['activities-heart'].forEach(element => {
            this.datos.push(element.value);
            this.datos.forEach(item => {
              console.log(item.restingHeartRate);
              
            });
    
         
        });
      
      })
  }
```

Api:

```
{
            "activities-heart": [
                {
                    "dateTime": "number",
                    "value": {
                        "customHeartRateZones": [],
                        "heartRateZones": [
                            {
                                "caloriesOut": number,
                                "max": number,
                                "min": number,
                                "minutes": number,
                                "name": "name"
                            },
                            {
                                "caloriesOut": number,
                                "max": number,
                                "min": number,
                                "minutes": number,
                                "name": "name"
                            },
                            {
                                "caloriesOut": number,
                                "max": number,
                                "min": number,
                                "minutes": number,
                                "name": "name"
                            },
                            {
                                "caloriesOut": number,
                                "max": number,
                                "min": number,
                                "minutes": number,
                                "name": "name"
                            }
                        ],
                        "restingHeartRate": number
                    }
                },
    ]
    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo tienes casi conseguido, pero te falta descender al interior de la propiedad `value`.

En vez de:

```
console.log(item.restingHeartRate);
```

Usa:

```
console.log(item.value.restingHeartRate);
```

Te muestro un ejemplo con tu definición:

```js
const actividades = {
  "activities-heart": [
    {
      "dateTime": "number",
      "value": {
        "customHeartRateZones": [],
        "heartRateZones": [
          {
            "caloriesOut": "number",
            "max": "number",
            "min": "number",
            "minutes": "number",
            "name": "name"
          },
          {
            "caloriesOut": "number",
            "max": "number",
            "min": "number",
            "minutes": "number",
            "name": "name"
          },
          {
            "caloriesOut": "number",
            "max": "number",
            "min": "number",
            "minutes": "number",
            "name": "name"
          },
          {
            "caloriesOut": "number",
            "max": "number",
            "min": "number",
            "minutes": "number",
            "name": "name"
          }
        ],
        "restingHeartRate": "number"
      }
    }
  ]
};

actividades["activities-heart"].forEach(actividad => {
  console.log(
    "Fecha actividad: ",
    actividad.dateTime,
    ", restingHeartRate: ", 
    actividad.value.restingHeartRate
  );
});
```